# Class not found error when moving to host?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to make a new Facebook app and got hosting from Asmallorange. The app works perfectly in my local environment that is running PHP 5.5.14.

The app consists of packages that were imported by Composer and autoloaded in my app.

The app in itself is a Slim app and consists of Laravel's Eloquent ORM. I followed tutorials online to integrate those two, and it works perfectly in my local environment.

The code is as follows.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';  

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;  

$capsule = new Capsule; 

$capsule->addConnection(array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'test',
    'username'  => 'test',
    'password'  => 'password',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => ''
));

$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

It works perfectly in my local environment. Just not on the server and fails with this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager' not found in /home/moz/public_html/app/index.php
```

Referring to line 2 above. I have looked everywhere and couldn't find a solution yet.

Comment: How are you deploying the app to the server?

Comment: I am using this little PHP deployment tool: https://github.com/banago/PHPloy

Comment: Have you checked the server to see if the `vendor` directory, which should contain the `illuminate/database` package, was deployed correctly. Because generally **not found** in this context can mean two things: autoloading is not done properly by Composer or the file containing the necessary class might be missing. There might be something going wrong with the deployment process.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks a lot for your replies. Everything was correctly uploaded on my server and so I contacted my host to look into this issue. Apparently, they had an old version of PHP and upgraded it. The issue is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your deployment tool has uploaded the `autoload_classmap.php` file found in the `vendors/composer` directory. Uploading this should fix the problem.

Alternatively you could get composer to rebuild the `autoload_classmap.php` file on the server by running the following in the command line from same directory as composer...

```
php composer dump-autoload
```